# What's the regular expression that matches a square bracket?

Tags: regex

I want a regex that matches a square bracket `[`. I haven't found one yet. I think I tried all possibilities, but haven't found the right one. What is a valid regex for this?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

How about using backslash `\` in front of the square bracket. Normally square brackets match a character class.

Comment: In case you are trying to write this regex in C# you have have to use \\ in front of the square bracket.

Comment: Actually I don't know where it works and why did the answer receive such a high rank.

Comment: The question asks about regular expressions, not about how to encode them in a host language which hijacks the backslash for its own use. If you are in a place where a shell or language parser will parse or otherwise process backslashes, you probably need to double the backslash, but that's not what this specific question is asking about.

Answer (score 67):

Try using `\\[`, or simply `\[`.

Comment: In a vanilla JS script, double backslash works for me.

Answer (score 40):

If you want to match an expression starting with `[` and ending with `]`, use `\[[^\]]*\]`.

Here is the meaning of each part (as explained at [www.regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com)):
[image]

Comment: can you tell us about it? The roof `^` means `not` in square bracket that is a character class.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Roy, that's just what I wanted to do

Answer (score 13):

Are you escaping it with `\`?

```
/\[/
```

Here's a helpful resource to get started with Regular Expressions:

[Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 10):

If you're looking to find both variations of the square brackets at the same time, you can use the following pattern which defines a range of *either* the `[` sign *or* the `]` sign: `/[\[\]]/`

Comment: You can omit the first backslash. `[[\]]` will match either bracket. In some regex dialects (e.g. grep) you can omit the backslash before the `]` if you place it immediately after the `[` (because an empty character class would never be useful): `[][]`. But that doesn't work in Java or JavaScript.

Comment: I was trying `sed -r 's|[\[\]]|!|g'`, but that was only matching the entire phrase once.  I wanted to keep my expression explicit, but this was the only efficient combination that worked for me: `s|[][]|!|g`

Answer (score 7):

In general, when you need a character that is "special" in regexes, just prefix it with a `\`. So a literal `[` would be `\[`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove the `[` or the `]`, use the expression:  `"\\[|\\]"`.

The two backslashes escape the square bracket and the pipe is an "or".

Comment: Thank you!! None of the other answers worked for me.

I was trying to split a json array string into a Java array.. So I had to remove the quotes and square brackets, then split on the comma `["item1" , "item2"]`

Comment: In the general case, the two backslashes are wrong here. In some languages (like Java, Python if not in a literal `r"..."` string, etc) you need to backslash the backslash to pass it through to the regex engine as a single backslash, but that's a (mis)feature of the host language, and not a correct answer for a question asking simply about regular expressions without a specific host language.

Answer (score 4):

does it work with an antislash before the `[` ?

`\[` or `\\[` ?

Answer (score 2):

For a pure exgex, it's simple:

1 /[]abcde]/ - it's the way to include the ']' in the class.

2 /[abc[de]/ - freely put anything else inside the brackets, including the '['. (Most of the meta-characters lose their special meaning inside '[]').

3 Test(verify) your regex w/ 'grep' or 'vim' etc. first.(They are easy-going guys.)

4 It's not too late to try inserting '\' at this moment if your scripting environment doesn't agree.

Comment: Really nice trick. I tried everything to include square brackets with `find -regex` and your solution was the only one that worked: `-not -regex "[][a-zA-Z0-9/.() ßÄÖÜäöüàéèí_-]+"` (this even uses the trick to include hyphen without escaping by placing it as last character in the class).

Answer (score -1):

The below expression is able to detect the timing **65**

```
\[(?<timeElpsed>\d+)ms\]
```

from the below log:

[2022-12-16T04:51:55.993+0000] [ INFO] [scala-execution-context-global-75] [200 OK]: [100.107.99.132] [65ms] "content-length: