# How can I make character "[" and "]" as the pattern in RegExp() function?

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters

As the title above, I want to know how to make these two characters be a pattern in RegExp() function in javascript. 
I have tried to put a backlash before it. It works for another special chars, but not for these two.
This is my current pattern :

```
var disallowed_char=new RegExp("[~!@#$%\^&*()\{\}\\\|\'\"\;\:\.\,\>\<\=\_\+\`\?\/\-]");
// It works
```

I want char `[` and `]` be a part of the pattern, so I add these to the pattern :

```
var disallowed_char=new RegExp("[~!@#$%\^&*()\{\}\\\|\'\"\;\:\.\,\>\<\=\_\+\`\?\/\[\]\-]");
//I put it before - (minus) char, 
//because minus char won't work if placed at the first or in the middle of the pattern
//note : I have tried to put "[" and "]" in other place
//but still doesn't work
```

Is there any way to make it as I want?

Comment: [Here are some useful resources](http://google.com/#q=use+square+brackets+regex).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928072/whats-the-regular-expression-that-matches-a-square-bracket

Comment: Why are you using `var reg = new Regexp("string")` instead of `var reg = /literal/` where you don't need to escape ` \ ` ?

Comment: How to delete this post? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to declare a JavaScript regex:

```
var disallowed_char=/\[/;
var disallowed_char=new RegExp("\\[");
```

When you use the second notation, you need to double escape the backslash because it is already an escape character in JavaScript strings.