# What's the regular expression that matches a square bracket? (Part II)

Tags: regex

This is a continuation of the [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928072/whats-the-regular-expression-that-matches-a-square-bracket) because none of the answers there produced the intended result. I am getting super wierd behavior using regexes to match dates. I want to match the following dates:

```
[month-day]
```

Such as:

```
"[01-23]" // January 23rd is a valid date
"[02-31]" // February 31st is an invalid date
"[02-16]" // valid
"[ 6-03]" // invalid format
```

Here is my regex:

```
regex = /\[^[0-1][1-9]\-[0-3][0-9]\]/
```

I tried to put both a single `\` and double `\` infront of brackets but nothing seems to be working for matching these dates. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect the `^` to do?

Comment: To match the first bracket in the expression

Comment: It's not going to do that. In that context, it will be treated as a literal caret. I think what you actually mean is this /^\[[0-1][1-9]\-[0-3][0-9]\]/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your regex is the placement of the start-of-line anchor `^` *after* the initial square bracket. This cannot happen, so your regex never matches anything.

Move the anchor to the beginning of your expression to fix the problem:

```
regex = /^\[[0-1][1-9]\-[0-3][0-9]\]/
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the "start of line" character `^` first:

```
regex = /^\[[0-1][1-9]-[0-3][0-9]\]/
```

And you don't need to escape the middle minus `-` in that context.

Answer (score 1):

You put the anchor `^` in the wrong place. It has to be in the very front or it'll never match. Moreover, your regex doesn't even work the way you want it to work:

https://regex101.com/r/tV8hH7/1

Comment: Ah alright. Best of luck to you then unless you want help with that too