# Javascript Regex replace [0] and not 0

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I would like to replace every instance of [0] in my HTML but the regex I am using now replaces all 0s not just [0]. Here's what I have:

```
var clone = clone.html().replace(/[0]/g, total); // Total is a number that increments
```

An example of what I would replace is something like:

```
<input id="Items[0].Id" name="Items[0].Id" value="0" type="text" />
```

But the above Javascript replaces the 0 in value="0", any ideas where I am falling through?

Comment: Please someone reclose with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928072/whats-the-regular-expression-that-matches-a-square-bracket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to escape the opening square bracket:

```
var clone = clone.html().replace(/\[0]/g, total);
```

If you leave it like that (`[0]`) it will be treated like a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) consisting of only the character `0`.

Comment: There is no need to escape the `]` symbol here.

Comment: @w0lf thanks that seem to have done the trick...