# Need a way of finding special characters in data using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, data-cleaning

I am trying to find special characters in any of my fields that are not in the range of a-zA-Z0-9. However if I try this query:

```
select Name from table where Name like '%[?]%'
```

I get two records:

- ???? ?????
- Fixed?????

Which is what I want. However, since I don't know what the special chars will be I need to use an exclusion of data that has mixed characters:

```
select Name from table where Name NOT like '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

Since this excludes all records with a-zA-Z0-9 I only get:

- ???? ?????

But I also need to get the 'Fixed?????' result. I need to get the data that has the special character merged into it.

I am bit at a loss as how to do this. I've seen this done with shell scripts or 'vi' (LIST), but in SQL that's not so easy.

Has anyone out there solved this?

Comment: The function you want is patindex.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
select Name from table where Name like '%[^0-9a-zA-Z ]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for replying. I had tried your suggestions but I was still getting more results. However, it looks like you can get very specific with the exclusion. Eventually I ended up adding results from the data I got.

Like this:

```
select Name from table where Name LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z() -._/\:=,]%'
```

This finally gave me what I was looking for. Although new issue I have now is how to suppress the [] brackets which apparently also are found in the data:

- ???? ?????
- HP PCI 10/100Base-TX Core [100BASE-TX,FD,AUTO,TT=1500]
- Fixed?????

Adding those brackets into the query breaks the array boundary:

```
'%[^0-9a-zA-Z() -._/\:=,**[]**]%'
```

However, this is something I can handle. As long as I am not getting "all" the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928072/whats-the-regular-expression-that-matches-a-square-bracket escape them with \ or \\  `'%[^0-9a-zA-Z() -._/:=,\[\]]%'`

Comment: in SQL you escape a LIKE clause like this `... WHERE x LIKE '%\[%' ESCAPE '\'` Note you get to choose your escape character, so you can choose whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

```
LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%'
```

numbers (0-9), lowercase alphas (a-z), uppercase alphas (A-Z). The "^" makes that a "NOT" one of these things