# How to choose a word that is in brackets from the sentence?

Tags: python, string, list

How to choose
`[Andrey]` and `[21]` from `info`?

```
info = "my name is [Andrey] and I am [21] years old"
result = ["[Andrey]", "[21]"];
```

Comment: SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not solving your tasks. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim (word for word) into your question. Providing pure "Gimme Code For Problem ...." questions are downvotet and closed fast - add your code and what you researched so we see you _trieed_ to solve it yourself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the regular expression that matches a square bracket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928072/whats-the-regular-expression-that-matches-a-square-bracket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may choose to regex method.

Or simply use list comprehension for your use case here:

```
>>> print([ lst[index] for index in [3,7] ])
['[Andrey]', '[21]']
```

But another way, You first convert your string to list and then choose by index method with the help of `itemgetter`:

```
>>> info = "my name is [Andrey] and I am [21] years old"
>>> lst = info.split()
>>> lst
['my', 'name', 'is', '[Andrey]', 'and', 'I', 'am', '[21]', 'years', 'old']
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> print(itemgetter(3,7)(lst))
('[Andrey]', '[21]')
```

Comment: if you don't know how many words in the sentence, for example the word in brackets will be like [Al Burhani Ibn kasir], and at this time how to choose this from sentence

Answer (score 2):

I am sure other ways would be better. But I tried this and it worked.
If you want to extract characters inside [] without knowing its position, you can use this method:
Run a for loop through string
If you find character [
append all the next characters in a string until you find ]
you can add these strings in a list to fetch result together. Here is the code.

```
info = "my name is [Andrey] and I am [21] years old"
s=[]    #list to collect searched result
s1=""   #elements of s
for i in range(len(info)):
    if info[i]=="[":
        while info[i+1] != "]":
            s1 += info[i+1]
            i=i+1
        s.append(s1)
        s1=""
        #make s1 empty to search for another string inside []
print s
```

Output will be:

```
['Andrey', '21']
```