# How do I match something between brackets using regex?

Tags: python

```
import re
string1 = 'thisIsSomeText    [128Kb]'
print(string1)
string2 = re.sub('[*]', '', string1)
print(string2)
```

```
thisIsSomeText    [128Kb]
thisIsSomeText    [128Kb]
```

my issue is that I need to remove `[filesize]` from the end of a string. The syntax is killing me here and im struggling to understand what the proper format is for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the regular expression that matches a square bracket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928072/whats-the-regular-expression-that-matches-a-square-bracket)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to escape your `[` and `]` characters with `\`

```
>>> import re
>>> string1 = 'thisIsSomeText    [128Kb]'
>>> re.sub(r'\[.*\]', '', string1)
'thisIsSomeText    '
```

You could also `str.strip` afterwards to remove the trailing whitespace

```
>>> re.sub(r'\[.*\]', '', string1).strip()
'thisIsSomeText'
```

Comment: okay i understand escaping the brackets now. but what is the purpose of the ```.``` in there

Comment: The `.` means "any character" and `*` means "0 or more", so together `.*` means "0 or more of any character" between your brackets

Comment: @Maxwell, here's a pretty handy tool that you can use to explain and test regular expressions https://regex101.com/r/6F8Uwd/1

Comment: @Maxwell Star `*` is a *suffix* meaning "zero or more", so `\[*` would mean "zero or more open-brackets", which is not what you want. `.` means "any character except a newline".