# How to make this pattern [u123] in regex?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, match

I am trying to make a regex pattern for the given input:-

Example:-

1. `"Hi how are you [u123]"`

   I want to take u123 from the above string.
2. `"Hi [u342], i am good"`

   in this, I want to take u342 from the above string.
3. "`I will count till 9, [u123]`"

   in this, I want to take u123 from the above string.
4. "`Hi [u1] and [u342]`"

   In this, I should get u1 and u342

123 and 342 is userId , it may be any number

I tried many references but I didn't get the desired result

[What's the regular expression that matches a square bracket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928072/whats-the-regular-expression-that-matches-a-square-bracket)

[Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets)

Comment: Spec seems unclear. What is special about 123 and 342? `s.match(/\d+/)` trivially does this. If you just want stuff in brackets starting with a `u`, you can add lookarounds `s.match(/(?<=\[u)\d+(?=\])/g)`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not really asking what it means, I'm asking what the logic behind the pattern is. I'm guessing the magic pattern is `<open bracket><literal u><some digits><close bracket>` but it could be anything as far as I can tell. Is there always 3 digits? Is the `u` important or does `[a123]` match as well? Have you tried writing a regex for this?

Comment: Yea you are right, digit length can be anything, like in leght 1 or 3 or 10 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex, `(?<=\[)(u\d+)(?=\])` which can be explained as

1. `(?<=\[)` specifies positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for `[`.
2. `u` specifies the character literal, `u`.
3. `\d+` specifies [one or more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) digits.
4. `(?=\])` specifies positive lookahead for `]`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "Hi how are you [u123]", "Hi [u342], i am good", "I will count till 9, [u123]",
                "Hi [u1] and [u342]" };
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(getId(s));
        }
    }

    static List<String> getId(String s) {
        return Pattern
                .compile("(?<=\\[)(u\\d+)(?=\\])")
                .matcher(s).results()
                .map(MatchResult::group)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[u123]
[u342]
[u123]
[u1, u342]
```

Note that [`Matcher#results`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) was added as part of Java SE 9. Also, if you are not comfortable with `Stream` API, given below is a solution without using `Stream`:

```
static List<String> getId(String s) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[)(u\\d+)(?=\\])").matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        list.add(matcher.group());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: i cant find results() , i am doing this in android java!, i am using java1.8

Comment: @iamkdblue - I've posted a solution without using `Stream` API also.

Comment: Arvind Sir can i use same regex with array split function?

Comment: Kuldeep - What is your exact requirement? I suggest you post a new question so that I or other contributors can look into it.

Comment: Sir I am trying to split [uAnyNumber]  within string, I tried above method reges but not getting same result. can you help sir ?

Comment: Yea same as above!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229515/discussion-between-arvind-kumar-avinash-and-iamkdblue).

Comment: @iamkdblue - In order to split the string on these tokens, you need to use `\[u\d+\]`. Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/KHznHd).