# sed pattern substitution not working - target file not changing

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replate a pattern (that contains many specials chars) with a simple string that I have in a file called "file". I''m using sed to get it done. The command runs without any exception but the target file remains the same...

I'm trying to replace this:

```
<%=ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]%>
```

with this (the content in the file):

```
88ce3e2c0fa0b667567dc370f8c62019ee88f1628ee1586651d7ea4a0faf18d0dbccaeb3f21c46109d2087ff31f07cf3734ce7a38f64f5a92cdf91dcb3494d1f** ... in a file called **secrets.yml
```

That's the commands I've tried but doesn't seem to work:

```
sed -i 's/<%=ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]%>/$(cat file)/g' config/secrets.yml
```

also tried with variables this way, but nothing changed:

```
var1="<%=ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]%>" && var2="`cat file`" && sed -i 's/$var1/$var2/g' config/secrets.yml
```

Does anyone have an idea what i'm missing here?

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing exactly what your strings and command are; please use [an appropriate code format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), so they're shown literally. But from what I can see, it looks like you have something in square-brackets in the pattern, and in a regular expression that has a [special meaning that probably isn't what you want](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html). To match a literal bracket, see ["What's the regular expression that matches a square bracket?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928072)

Comment: Can `file` ever contain `&` or ```\``` or `/` characters? If so sed may not be your best choice, see [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed).

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues I see with what you have currently:

1. `'s/<%=ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]%>/$(cat file)/g'` is using single quotes which will prevent interpretation of the command to `cat` the file
2. You need to escape a few things in the comparison string like:
   `<%=ENV\[\"SECRET_KEY_BASE\"\]%>`

Putting those things together, this is working for me:

```
sed -i "s/<%=ENV\[\"SECRET_KEY_BASE\"\]%>/$(cat file)/g" secrets.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Certain special characters must be escaped when using sed. In this case it's the square brackets and the double quotes in the string to be replaced.

```
sed -i "s|<%=ENV\[\"SECRET_KEY_BASE\"\]%>|88ce3e2c0fa0b667567dc370f8c62019ee88f1628ee1586651d7ea4a0faf18d0dbccaeb3f21c46109d2087ff31f07cf3734ce7a38f64f5a92cdf91dcb3494d1f|g" secrets.yml
```